# Return the result for max repeated property like name in some of the node ? NEO4J , any function or query?

Tags: database-design, neo4j, cypher

i have 3 nodes

```
e1 : person {name:'aj',age:'14',gender:'male'}
e2 : person {name:'kj',gender:'female'}
e3 : person {name:'lj',age:'34'}
```

i want name as a returned result because this property is repeated to most any query or function in neo4j ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is your use-case for that?

You can probably only do it in the core-api using node.getPropertyKeys() and counting them in a map and sorting it in the end by counted.

Usually you know from your domain which property is used most often.

Comment: Bro , i can't do it bycore api. i have to do it by queries only !